# JEE5, injecting EJB from rest (servlet 2.5 SPEC)

Tags: jakarta-ee, ejb

My application has 3 modules:

```
- ear
- ejb
- web
```

This is my EJB:

```
@Stateless
public class ServiceBean implements Service {

    public String getSomething() {
        return "burp";
    }
}

@Remote
public interface Service {
     String getSomething();
}
```

This is the rest:

```
@Path("something/")
public class SomethingRest {


    @EJB(name = "Service")
    Service service;

    @GET
    @Produces(MediaType.TEXT_PLAIN)
    public String get() {

        return service.getSomething();
    }

}
```

The issue is service is never injected.

I've also tried to add on web.xml

```
<ejb-ref>
    <ejb-ref-name>Service</ejb-ref-name>
    <ejb-ref-type>Session</ejb-ref-type>
    <remote>it.infocert.backend.ejb.Service</remote>
</ejb-ref>
```

but it doesn't work. Anything missing ?

Comment: What does "it doesn't work" mean? Do you have an exception or a stacktrace that describes the error?

Comment: no, service is just null, like annotation is ignored

Comment: what version of jax-rs is your container providing?  i know the first few versions of jax-rs do NOT provide injection into endpoint providers.  this support was eventually added.  you may need to update the container you are running inside.

Comment: It's installed jersey 1.18.3, I think it implements jax-rs 1.1